# Google Fonts (Roboto) on Safari iOS

Tags: ios, css, fonts, safari, mobile-safari

I'm using the Roboto font on my site and it's not rendering properly on Safari for iOS (i.e. it's not using the Roboto font)

I already tried adding the following to my css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');
```

as well as adding the following:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'),
       local('Roboto-Regular'),
       url('fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'),
       local('Roboto-Medium'),
       url('fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

to no avail.

I would greatly appreciate some help solving this. Has anyone solved this?